# How to set inside margin for variable number of inline elements?

Tags: html, css

I want the output to look like the following jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/d3uGp/

however that's hard-coded for two things:
 - row size of three
 - column size of three (along with row size of three)

Basically I am wondering if there is an elegant solution to having zero outside margins for a variable number of inline elements - for the sake of responsive design.

Code below:

html

```
<ul>
    <li></li><li>
    </li><li>
    </li><li>
    </li><li>
    </li><li>
    </li><li>
    </li><li>
    </li><li>
    </li>
</ul>
```

css

```
ul,li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul { 
    background-color: black;
    width: 140px;
}

ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    vertical-align:top;
    background-color: gray;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

ul > li:nth-child(1n + 4) {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

ul > li:nth-child(3n + 2) {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I use padding on the li's to achieve this in situations where they are the same size.  http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/rfehE

Comment: Basicly i would say: mediaqueries to reset the nth-child-rules for horizontal margins. For vertical margin: margin-top for boxes, + double negative margin at bottom for parent, to finish :position:relative for childs + negative equal to margin. You can use a preprocessor to easily generate your mediaqueries :)

Comment: @sheriffderek: But see how there is a padding on the right?  Basically, the parent <ul> is 8px wider than it needs to be due to that padding-right.  I can see where this would still be a solution, assuming you offset the parent by 8 in some manner - still seems somewhat hack'ish though.

Comment: @GCyrillus: Yeah, I try to steer from negative margins when I can - though sometimes the best answer calls for it.  Same with the media queries generation - honestly never thought of that.

Thanks for both of your guys/girls(?) help.

Comment: mediaquerie : example with a breaking point at 800px goes 3 or 4 cols : http://jsfiddle.net/d3uGp/1/

Comment: Awesome - I've used SASS before and can see where a function would work great in a situation like this.

Comment: @PhilOlson - if you look at the code - it's actually a tiny trick - with the parent shift --- but not really a hack --- and trades 10 hacks for 1 if you think of it that way. removing and overriding the right margin with nth of type is find by hand up to 4 or so... but after that it gets tedious. I've been working on grids like that for 3 years - and that seems to be the only way to get real consistent gutter sizes. You have to have the right scenario for it though. The real problem I find now, is dealing with their heights -

Comment: @sheriffderek - very true.  I didn't catch the 8px offset when I looked at your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using hard coded html, you can generate the code on the fly using javascript. The parameters that need to be known are:

- Number of cells
- Cell dimensions
- Cell margin (right and bottom)
- Number of columns

Here goes the code I've written:

**HTML**

```
<div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    background: #000;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.innerCell {
    float: left;
    background: #999;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var cell = 12;
var cell_dimension = 50;
var margin = 10;
var columns = 3;

var rows = Math.ceil(cell/columns);
var container_dimension_width = cell_dimension*columns + margin*(columns-1);
var container_dimension_height = cell_dimension*rows + margin*(rows-1);
var list_dimension_width = (cell_dimension+margin)*columns;
var list_dimension_height = (cell_dimension+margin)*rows;

var output = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
output.style.height = container_dimension_height+'px';
output.style.width = container_dimension_width+'px';
var list = document.createElement('ul');
output.appendChild(list);
list.style.height = list_dimension_height+'px';
list.style.width = list_dimension_width+'px';
for(var i=0;i<cell;i++) {
    var innerCell = document.createElement('li');
    innerCell.setAttribute('class','innerCell');
    list.appendChild(innerCell);
    document.getElementsByTagName('li')[i].style.height = cell_dimension+'px';
    document.getElementsByTagName('li')[i].style.width = cell_dimension+'px';
    document.getElementsByTagName('li')[i].style.marginRight = margin+'px';
    document.getElementsByTagName('li')[i].style.marginBottom = margin+'px';
}
```

You can try out the JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/amitdatta/r5x5Y/
Try alternate the four parameters as mentioned above!

Comment: That is definitely another solution to the problem that I haven't thought of - especially because whether it be server side or client side, these lists will usually be driven by data and will thus be dynamically created in the first place.  My particular scenario happens to be more pure html/css.

Thanks all for your input.  I'll mark this as the solution only because no other answers were listed, but I like sheriffderek and GCyrillus' solutions as well.